# Why am I experiencing a memory trouble/leaks in UWP/C# app

Tags: c#, memory, uwp

I created extension to `IOrderedIEnumerable`
which looks like this:

```
internal static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IOrderedEnumerable<T> list)
{
    var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (var p in list)
        observableCollection.Add(p);
    return observableCollection;
}
```

Also I have a page which looks like:

```
private ObservableCollection<BusStopName> _ListOfBusStopNames;

public BusStopsListPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.SetIsBackFromPageAllowed(true);

    _ListOfBusStopNames = Timetable.Instance.BusStopsNames
                                   .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                                   .ToObservableCollection<BusStopName>();
}
```

And in this page i have a listview which has binding to `_ListOfBusStopNames`

`Timetable.Instance.BusStopsNames` has 2812 entries.

When I'm navigating to this page, application memory is growing up to infinity numbers. It looks like (red line is moment when I navigated to this page):

[image]

In memory snapshot we can see that this thing is making this problem:
[image]

I don't have any idea what it can be. **Do anyone have any idea?**

When I change instance constructor to:

```
public BusStopsListPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.SetIsBackFromPageAllowed(true);

    _ListOfBusStopNames = new ObservableCollection<BusStopName>();
}
```

everything works nice. Also, when I changed in this constructor manually `List` ( `Timetable.Instance.BusStopsNames` ) to `ObservableCollection`, it works great too.

**EDIT**
Hm.. i tried to make an example how to reproduce it, and i get to a solution for it. It is very confusing, so if someone can explain why this is happening it will be nice :)

1. Create UWP APP
2. Add in MainPage.xaml only this: `<Frame Name="MainFrame" />`
3. In code-behind put:`this.Loaded += (s, e) => MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));`
4. Create new blank page with name `BlankPage1`
5. In View of BlankPage add this:

   ```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
       <StackPanel> 
           <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind _ListOfTestClasses}">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TestClass">
                       <Grid>
                           <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                       </Grid>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>
       </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
   ```
6. In code-behind put:

   ```
       public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
       {
           private List<TestClass> _List;
           private ObservableCollection<TestClass> _ListOfTestClasses;
           public BlankPage1() {
               this.InitializeComponent();
               GenerateTestData();
               _ListOfTestClasses = _List.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToObservableCollection<TestClass>();
           }
           private void GenerateTestData() {
               _List = new List<TestClass>();
               for(int i = 0; i < 2800; i++)
                   _List.Add(new TestClass() { Id = i, Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
           }
       }

       public static class Extension {
           public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IOrderedEnumerable<T> list) {
               var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
               foreach (var p in list)
                   observableCollection.Add(p);
               return observableCollection;
           }
       }
       public class TestClass {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
       }
   ```
7. Run the app

So.. you can see that app is lagging and memory is going taking more and more.. And now.. try to delete in `BlankPage1` view `StackPanel`. And now run the app.

Comment: With a List WPF creates a strong reference to the collection. Fix it by using ObservableCollection

Comment: I don't see how your graphic demonstrates a problem. It shows an object about 100K in size, a far cry from the 200MB your trace appears to involve. It's worth keeping in mind that .NET (and managed systems in general) tend to be memory-hungry. They may allocate large amounts of RAM temporarily from the OS, and then even if those objects no longer are around, keep the allocated memory in case you use it for something else. If you want good advice, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I updated the post. Check it out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem. The issue is the misuse of panels in XAML. A `Grid` will stretch to fit its container's boundaries and cascade this to its children. A `StackPanel` will only cascade the size of the opposing orientation.

For example, when you have `<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>`, all children will receive the width of the parent `Grid`, but not the height. Because the orientation is vertical, the height will be infinite to allow the panel to stack its children based on their requested heights.

When you have `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>`, all children will receive the height of the parent `Grid`, but not the width. Same reason as above. It needs to stack horizontally.

**So...**, when you have a `<ListView/>` inside a `<StackPanel/>`:

```
<StackPanel>
   <ListView>...</ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

The `StackPanel` is telling the `ListView` to render its size with height = infinity. And therefore, all 2,800 items in your `ListView` are actually being rendered, not virtualized.

You have to avoid putting ListViews in StackPanels when the orientations are the same.

This should work:

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ListView>...</ListView>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

... but it's silly.